# Python import module fails with __init__.py

Tags: python, import

I have two folders each containing several python modules:

```
 1. pyA:

  /a
 /b
 /c

 2. pyB:

  /d
 /e
 /f
```

I have added the `__init__.py` (empty) to both folders.
However when I try to import pyB in pyA, I get the "ImportError: No module named pyB".

I have looked through the already existing answers and couldn't find the solution. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are the `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` directories all in the same directory?

Comment: No the a,b, c are files and in folder pyA and d, e, f are in pyB. I have added sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("..")) to my file where I do the import and it works. But then I should add this line to any file that I have an import from the other folder in?

Answer (score 0):

Until unless root folder of pyB is in PYTHONPATH, this is expected. Files inside pyA folder is not aware of where pyB is.

(Or) please do below:

```
import sys

sys.path.append(/path/to/parentfolderofPyB)
import pyB
```

Alternatively if you are sure that you don't use pyA in pyB, you can move pyB inside pyA folder

Comment: Where should I add this? To each and every file?

Comment: Add those 2 lines to all py modules in PyA where ever you need pyB import

Comment: What about using python package then? It just seems like there should be some better solution.

Comment: Even if it is a python package, it should in system path or PYTHONPATH for other modules to access it

Comment: I figured I can add the one level upper folder to syspath on my __main__ module and then just simply use the packages:

Comment: import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..'))